Azure Webjob not running
We have a webjob project that is a timer based project. It runs locally (offline in VS2022 debugger), but we are using devops to build as a linux target '--runtime linux-x64' and deploying to App_Data/jobs/triggered/Jobnamefolder/appfiles, and when deployed it does not appear to run, or at least there is no evidence the job exists - it is not shown on the webjobs page - more on that later.
The job is basically the following:
using My.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace My.WebJobs
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureWebJobs(webJobsBuilder =>
                {
                    webJobsBuilder.AddTimers();

                })

                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configBuilder) =>
                {
                    configBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                })
                .ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
                {
                    b.AddConsole();
                })
                .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                {
                    var configuration = context.Configuration;
                    var connectionString = configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];

                    services.AddDbContext<DatabaseService>(options =>
                    {
                        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
                    });
                })
                .Build();



            using (host)
            {
                await host.RunAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}


and
using Azure;
using Azure.Communication.Email;
using My.Data;
using My.Domain;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace My.WebJobs
{
    public class Functions
    {
        private readonly DatabaseService _databaseService;

        public Functions(DatabaseService databaseService)
        {
            _databaseService = databaseService;
        }

        public void TimerTriggeredFunction([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo timerInfo, ILogger logger)
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"Function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            SendFeedbackEmails(logger).Wait();
        }

        // this attribute defines what function will be triggered by the web job
        [NoAutomaticTrigger]
        public async Task SendFeedbackEmails(ILogger logger)
        {
...
        }
    }
}

I have 2 functions, one a TimerTrigger and the other flagged with a NoAutomaticTrigger as it is not called Run.
We also have a 'settings.job' with "schedule": {"0 * * * * *"}
Our website runs up fine but the webjob never runs.
I can SSH into the site and confirm the files are in the folder and log stream shows them copying too.
Logs show nothing related to the webjob unless we go to the Azure Portal webjobs page, in which case a background exception occurs:
2024-07-09T00:20:23.0533898Z Exception StackTrace :    at Kudu.Services.Diagnostics.HttpRequestExtensions.ForwardToContainer(String route, HttpRequestMessage request) in /tmp/KuduLite/Kudu.Services/Diagnostics/HttpRequestExtensions.cs:line 22
2024-07-09T00:20:23.0725163Z    at Kudu.Services.Jobs.JobsController.ForwardJobRequestToContainer(String route) in /tmp/KuduLite/Kudu.Services/Jobs/JobsController.cs:line 200
2024-07-09T00:20:23.0725763Z    at Kudu.Services.Jobs.JobsController.ListAllJobs() in /tmp/KuduLite/Kudu.Services/Jobs/JobsController.cs:line 28
2024-07-09T00:20:23.0725790Z    at lambda_method132(Closure , Object , Object[] )
2024-07-09T00:20:23.0725821Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
2024-07-09T00:20:23.0725850Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
2024-07-09T00:20:23.0725876Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
2024-07-09T00:20:23.0725962Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
2024-07-09T00:20:23.0725984Z --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
2024-07-09T00:20:23.0726010Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
2024-07-09T00:20:23.0726036Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
2024-07-09T00:20:23.0726059Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
2024-07-09T00:20:23.0732366Z --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
2024-07-09T00:20:23.0732406Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
2024-07-09T00:20:23.0732430Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
2024-07-09T00:20:23.0732456Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
2024-07-09T00:20:23.0732502Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
2024-07-09T00:20:23.0732529Z --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
2024-07-09T00:20:23.0732555Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
2024-07-09T00:20:23.0732582Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
2024-07-09T00:20:23.0732604Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
2024-07-09T00:20:23.0732630Z    at Kudu.Services.Web.Tracing.TraceMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /tmp/KuduLite/Kudu.Services.Web/Tracing/TraceMiddleware.cs:line 107
2024-07-09T00:20:23.1611928Z [41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
2024-07-09T00:20:23.1612508Z       An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
2024-07-09T00:20:23.1612536Z       System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused (169.254.130.5:50555)
2024-07-09T00:20:23.1626364Z        ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused
2024-07-09T00:20:23.1626787Z          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 )
2024-07-09T00:20:23.1626817Z          at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs , ValueTask , CancellationToken )
2024-07-09T00:20:23.1626843Z          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String , Int32 , HttpRequestMessage , Boolean , CancellationToken )
2024-07-09T00:20:23.1626866Z          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2024-07-09T00:20:23.1626891Z          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String , Int32 , HttpRequestMessage , Boolean , CancellationToken )
2024-07-09T00:20:23.1626917Z          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage , Boolean , CancellationToken )
2024-07-09T00:20:23.1626946Z          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage , Boolean , CancellationToken )
2024-07-09T00:20:23.1626971Z          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage )
2024-07-09T00:20:23.1627045Z          at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken )
2024-07-09T00:20:23.1627071Z          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage , Boolean , CancellationToken )
2024-07-09T00:20:23.1627096Z          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage , Boolean , Boolean , CancellationToken )
2024-07-09T00:20:23.1627122Z          at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage , Boolean , CancellationToken )
2024-07-09T00:20:23.1627147Z          at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage , Boolean , CancellationToken )
2024-07-09T00:20:23.1627177Z          at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage , HttpCompletionOption , CancellationTokenSource , Boolean , CancellationTokenSource , CancellationToken )
2024-07-09T00:20:23.1627203Z          at Kudu.Services.Web.Tracing.TraceMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /tmp/KuduLite/Kudu.Services.Web/Tracing/TraceMiddleware.cs:line 107
2024-07-09T00:20:23.1627229Z          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context)
2024-07-09T00:20:23.1627256Z          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)

No documentation appears to quite say 'how' the webjob is running - I.e. what hosts the application or starts it.
Any ideas on how to diagnose beyond this point? Anything clearly wrong with what we have?
Thanks!
Edit: The pipeline build and package is as follows:

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/My.WebJobs.csproj'
    arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output/App_Data/jobs/triggered/My-WebJob --runtime linux-x64'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/My.WebApp.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output --runtime linux-x64'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false




deploying to App_Data/jobs/triggered/Jobnamefolder/appfiles, and when deployed it does not appear to run


WebJob files should correctly place in the App_Data/jobs/triggered/<JobName> directory and not in a subdirectory like appfiles.

For Linux deployments, you need a run.sh script instead of run.cmd.
Check the below azure-pipeline.yaml file for deployment.
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '6.x.x'
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet

- script: |
    dotnet build --configuration Release --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/webjob
  displayName: 'Build WebJob'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/webjob'
    artifactName: 'webjob'

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'AzureSubscription'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'YourWebAppName'
    packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/webjob'
    RuntimeStack: 'DOTNETCORE|6.0'

Status:

Result:

Modified/Updated answer
run.sh:
#!/bin/bash
# This is the command to start your .NET Core WebJob
dotnet My.WebJobs.dll


After adding check that the run.sh script has executable permissions.

chmod +x /home/site/wwwroot/App_Data/jobs/triggered/My-WebJob/run.sh

Project structure:
App_Data/
└── jobs/
    └── triggered/
        └── My-WebJob/
            ├── My.WebJobs.dll
            ├── run.sh
            └── settings.job


Thanks for the reply. When our webjob builds, it is a dotnet core application and so is a set of files (libraries etc.) along with the build file itself (in our instance My.Webjob (as linux build outputs are not EXE or .so but just the app name. I have included our pipeline code above where we are building and packaging.

Where does the run.sh go? I don't see anything in your deployment example. Do we need a run.sh in the WebJob folder?

Yes, for a Linux-based WebJob, you will need a run.sh script to start the .NET Core application because Linux does not use .exe files for execution. In the script we should include the run command for the .NET Core application. I have added the structure in my above answer.

ok, thanks. We were getting an error message just doing that, so I reached out to Microsoft. I have posted resolution in an answer here.

I ended up opening a support ticket with Microsoft.
The solution was to add an Environment variables to the Linux App Service to start making webjobs operate correctly as they require common storage between scale instances, they require storage to be available:
WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE = true
Additionally, the most useful info on webjobs can be found here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs
